Creating pdf file from bitmaps with selectable text using PDFdocument
I am turning pdf pages into bitmaps to be able to make changes on them in my applications then ı am  creating pdf files with bitmaps using pdfdocument class but final pdf file doesnt have selectable text when ı open it on other pdf editor applications
is there a way to apply text data on these bitmaps so they can be choosable when ı create the pdf file
  public void createpdf() throws IOException {
       
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
            
        for (int i = 0; i < pdfBitmaps.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = pdfBitmaps.get(i);


        
            PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(1080, 1920, i+ 1).create();
            PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);


            // Draw the bitmap onto the page
            Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
            Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new     ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));

            canvas.drawBitmap(decoded, 0f, 0f, null);
            document.finishPage(page);
        
        }

        
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "fınal_pdf_deneme");
        values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf");
        values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);


        Uri uri = ontentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),values);
        if (uri != null) {
            try (OutputStream outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)) {
                document.writeTo(outputStream);
                Toast.makeText(this, "File saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("PDF Directory", uri.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to save file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } finally {
                document.close();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create document", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

EDİT
This is the code to use apply OCR on the page bitmap you should apply this method after turnıng pdf pages into bitmap
  public void mlkitforembededtext(Bitmap bitmap, int pageIndex) {

    InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0);

    Task<Text> result = recognizer.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Text>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Text visionText) {
                    // Initialize lists for the current page
                    List<String> pageTextValues = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<Rect> pageBoundingBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<Float> pageTextSizes = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (Text.TextBlock block : visionText.getTextBlocks()) {
                        boundingBoxforsave = block.getBoundingBox();
                        for (Text.Line line : block.getLines()) {
                            boundingBoxforsave = line.getBoundingBox();
                            String textValue = line.getText();

                            //float textSize = boundingBoxforsave.height();
                            //float textSize = boundingBoxforsave != null ? boundingBoxforsave.height() : 0;

                            if (boundingBoxforsave != null && textValue != null) {
                                // Add text, bounding box, and size to the current page's lists

                                pageBoundingBoxes.add(boundingBoxforsave);
                                pageTextValues.add(textValue);

                                Log.i("MLKIT", "Text and bounding box added: " + textValue + " " + boundingBoxforsave.toString());
                            } else {
                                Log.e("MLKitError", "BoundingBox or Text is null");
                            }
                            for (Text.Element element : line.getElements()) {
                                for (Text.Symbol symbol : element.getSymbols()) {
                                    ArrayList<Text.Symbol> FORCOUNT = new ArrayList();
                                    FORCOUNT.add(symbol);
                                    float textSize = ( (float) boundingBoxforsave.width() /FORCOUNT.size());
                                    pageTextSizes.add(textSize);
                                    FORCOUNT.clear();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    // Store the current page's lists in the overall lists
                    allPageTextValues.add(pageIndex, pageTextValues);
                    allPageBoundingBoxes.add(pageIndex, pageBoundingBoxes);
                    allPageTextSizes.add(pageIndex, pageTextSizes);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // Handle the error
                    Log.e("MLKitError", "Text recognition failed", e);
                }
            });
}

And this is the code to use to implement text data on the pdf page before saving the file
 public void createpdf() throws IOException {
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

    for (int i = 0; i < pdfBitmaps.size(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = pdfBitmaps.get(i);
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), i + 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        canvas2 = page.getCanvas();

        // Draw the bitmap onto the page
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
        Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
        canvas2.drawBitmap(decoded, 0f, 0f, null);

       // Draw the detected text for the current page
        List<String> textValues = allPageTextValues.get(i);
        List<Rect> boundingBoxes = allPageBoundingBoxes.get(i);
        List<Float> textSizes = allPageTextSizes.get(i);


        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        textPaint.setTypeface(font);
        textPaint.setAlpha(1);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);



        for (int p = 0; p < boundingBoxes.size(); p++) {
            String text = textValues.get(p);
            Rect box = boundingBoxes.get(p);
            float textSize = textSizes.get(p);
            text.replace(" ","   ");

            textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
            // Calculate text dimensions
              float initialTextWidth = textPaint.measureText(text);

            // Calculate scaling factor
            float scalingFactor =( box.width()+50)/initialTextWidth;

            // Adjust font size
            textPaint.setTextSize(textSize * scalingFactor);
            Log.d("scalingfacto", "createpdf:scaling "+scalingFactor);

            Path fortext = new Path();
            fortext.moveTo(box.left,box.centerY());
            fortext.lineTo(box.right,box.centerY());

            canvas2.drawPath(fortext,textPaint);
            canvas2.drawTextOnPath(text,fortext,0,4,textPaint);
        }

        document.finishPage(page);
    }

And this way you can add textdata to final pdf files just adjust the box.width when calculating the scaling factor to make sure the text fills the entire path this way you can have more uniform text bounding boxes on the final pdf.

Sorry for the late answer ı was trying to make the code work. ı used MLkit OCR to detect the textdata and can save files with text data but now ı have a new problem. I can drawtext the text on ımageview which ı use to display pages but cant pick it.Is there way to make this work?

It's not really possible to do what you want with the PdfDocument class as it cannot edit existing PDF's it can only create new ones.
As soon as you render the existing PDF to a bitmap you loose all the structure and selectability, it just becomes a picture of all the elements in the pdf.
If you use the PdfDocument class and it's canvas to draw bitmaps to PDF then again you are just adding a picture of all the elements to the PDF, which is unselectable.
If you use the canvas drawText method on a PdfDocument canvas then this will be convert to a native PDF text element which is selectable.
Really you need to use a class that can edit the PDF structure like Apache PdfBox and it's Android version
With that you would load the document and render it to a Bitmap to display BUT when you want to add text you would add the text to the Content Stream in the position you want (an example) and re-render to display the original document with your changes.

This looks like the only logical way currently i am detecting the text and the bouinding boxes for each element on the page and trying to draw the text on the same position with transparent paint thank u for the suggestion

With PdfBox you can edit existing text elements as text as well as add new ones.

hey @Andrew Sorry for the late answer ı was trying to make the code work. I ve made it worked and published the code on the Edit section.Now ı have another problem related to topic. I am using İmageViews to display the pages and since ı have the textdata ı can write the data on the screen with drawtext but ı cant pick it like other apps do is there way to achieve that feature with ımageview
